# cant perform click without bringing the window to the foreground

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto to simulate a click without bringing the window to the foreground and keeping it unfocused. When I use click() it doesn't perform a click. I can do it with click_input, which works fine but the problem is that click_input brings the window to the foreground. I don't get any error when I use click()
Here is the simple code

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.Application().connect(path='nox.exe')
app.NoxPlayer.click(button="left",coords=(400, 640))
```

Comment: Your coordinates are probably supposed to be relative to the upper-left of the button, so you're clicking outside of the button.

Comment: @MarkRansom my coordinates should be right because if I replace click() with click_input() it clicks where I want it to

Answer (score -1):

As I noticed, your problem is that the desired window is not foreground, am I right?
if your problem is that, you can use pyautogui to bring the desired window in foreground:

```
import pyautogui
window=pyautogui.Widow(h) #Enter handle number of the window
window.activate()
```

if you don't know the window's handle, you can use:

```
windows=pyautogui.getAllWindows() #it gives you a list of all windows
for window in windows:
    print( window.title, window._hWnd )
```